# Why doesn't the javascript output anything?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

Why doesn't the javascript output anything? It should output some html code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--`

var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

function d64(input) {
    var output = new StringMaker();
    var chr1, chr2, chr3;
    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
    input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

    while (i < input.length) {
        enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

        chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
        chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
        chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

        output.append(String.fromCharCode(chr1));

        if (enc3 != 64) {
            output.append(String.fromCharCode(chr2));
        }
        if (enc4 != 64) {
            output.append(String.fromCharCode(chr3));
        }
    }

    return output.toString();
}

//-->
</script>

</head>
<body>
blah
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(d64("PGEgaHJlZj0ibWFpbHRvOnN0ZXZlbkBtYWlsaW5hdG9yLmNvbSI+c3RldmVuQG1haWxpbmF0b3IuY29tPC9hPg=="));</script><noscript>steven[|at|]mailinator[|dot|]com</noscript>
blah
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@@@@@22</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, did you see any red cross error indicator under FireFox? Or anything wrong from its FireBug console panel?

Comment: I don't, I'm using the public domain code off: http://rumkin.com/tools/compression/base64.php

Comment: Put alerts in your code to see what happens in the different parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StringMaker is not defined:

```
function d64(input) {
    var output = new StringMaker(); //<= what's this?
    ...
}
```

Comment: you need the <script language="JavaScript" src="/inc/js/browser_faster.js">

Comment: it is defined in browser_faster.js

Answer (score 0):

I am getting a javascript error. `StringMaker` is undefined. But `StringMaker` relates to [Java](http://docs.huihoo.com/javadoc/liferay/4.3/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/StringMaker.html) ?

Comment: You're confusing with StringBuilder or StringBuffer.